# ember if else conditionals

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a conditional statement which contains a link. If something is true, the I'd like it to link to a 'place a' if it is not true I'd like it to link to 'place b'. But I am getting a build error.

I removed the conditional statement, and just have a normal link (link-to) ...so just a link to one place my code builds fine. The build error is just when I try to have 2 links. See below:

```
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          {{if isShowingModal}}
          {{#link-to 'place-a'}}
          {{else}}
            {{#link-to 'place-b'}}
          {{/if}}
              <div class="card-block">
                  <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">The Place</h4>
              </div>
          {{/link-to}}

        </div>
```

The error says: Error: link-to doesn't match if - 8:19

application.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isShowingModal: false,
    actions: {

        showNavMenu: function() {
          this.toggleProperty('isShowingModal');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you are not ending link-to helper properly. it should end with `{{/link-to}}`
so in your case it will be

```
{{#link-to 'place-a' }} Place A {{\link-to}

{{#link-to 'place-b' }} Place B {{\link-to}
```

In your case complete code will be

```
<div class="card text-xs-center">
          {{if isShowingModal}}
           {{#link-to 'place-a' class='card-block fa fa-cogs'}}  
             The Place 
           {{/link-to}}
          {{else}}
            {{#link-to 'place-b' class='card-block fa fa-cogs'}}  
             The Place 
            {{/link-to}}
          {{/if}}         
</div>
```

For your help check it http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_link-to

Comment: I have closed the link-to at the bottom though? I would like the whole inside of .card (so both .card-block)'s to be a link.

Comment: thank you! No build error now. but the 2 diff links are not working. just Place a is working (when modal is showing, and when it is not showing). Think its something in my application. Have added the application.js code to my question now :-)

Comment: try to inspect your controller property from Ember inspector. install ember inspector in google chrome and than right click on browser and open ember inspector as we open console. and than go to controllers and select your controller, now you can inspect your controller properties.
accepting answer is better than simple thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because you haven't closed the link-to correctly. This will help you without duplicating your link-to statement.

```
<div class="card text-xs-center">
    {{#link-to (if showingModal "place-a" "place-b") class='card-block fa fa-cogs'}}
        <div class="card-block">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">The Place</h4>
        </div>
    {{/link-to}}
</div>
```